# Best practical priority queue data structure in the following workload?

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures

My goal to find what is the best data structure priority queue (PQ) given the following requirements:

1. The workload: Initially, we insert to the PQ a number of k elements. Next, there are N operation, where N>>k and very large. In each operation we take the minimal value of the PQ, and update it into a larger of into a larger value.
2. The data structure should be used for multithreading. This means, finding the minimal value and updating it into a larger value can be parallel. Of course, given L threads, the algorithm should work at O(N/L * log N) time.
3. The data structure should be cache efficient. This means, each thread should have locality of reference and be fast.
4. The data structure is *not* need to be space effect, although it is recommended to be one.

Now, there are serval PQ I can used, but all have problems:

1. A tree based solution (AVL, balanced tree, RB tree) or the skip-list solution are using link-lists, and thus not cache efficient. This is, as well Fibonacci/Pairing heaps.
2. The base heap solution is not cache efficient
3. The d-ary heap solution is not multithreaded easily.

My solution: I am thinking about using the d-ary heap solution, with a multi-threaded algorithm, where the SWAP operation is locked if it is already accessed by another thread. But I am not sure it will work.

Your thoughts?

Comment: With parallel threads accessing the PQ, there will be an undetermined amount of time between a pop and the following push of a larger value.  During this time other threads can pop values larger than what would eventually be pushed.  If you can put up with that, then you should look at options involving multiple independent queues and a less strict prioritization between them.

Comment: You are right.
But I think to avoid this case- why not lock the heap root from accessing?

Comment: I assume that most of the time dedicated for the heap workload is the heapify down operation (which is log n), and not the push of the larger value

Comment: Locks cause contention.  There's no point having multiple cores when all but one of them has to wait.  If contention isn't a problem, then none of the other things that you're worried about are problems, either.

Comment: Is the  pop operation of the queue supplying the min element or the max?  In other words, when you increase a key is it getting closer to being popped or farther away?

Comment: @matt it is temporary, since the first SWAP between the root and the children, the lock is set on the swapped choldren. This is while locking the whole heap, or using a single thread has worse performance,

Comment: @gene the min element.

Comment: Have you looked in the literature for prior work? A quick search for "concurrent priority queue" turns up a long history. https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_IPL_heaps.pdf  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.07053.pdf

Comment: @Gene Yes, but I don't know if it is being used in practice.